# Using SO as a Chatboard

Tags: discussion, edits

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30990576/user-count-didnt-change-by-1-rails) while removing typos from recent questions.

I could see that the way the OP had used the question to reply to each of his correspondents was not the orthodox style, but I was not sure how I might have handled it better by way of an improving edit.

I thought that asking here for more experienced eyes might be a way of learning the house moderating style.

In one way the OP is being polite and helpful, and in another he is *riding coach and horses* through the SO/SE genre of Q&A.

---

As the original nature of the problem may get lost in a [maze of twisty edits that all look alike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colossal_Cave_Adventure), I'll summarise the look and feel of the problem style here:

> Question ... blah blah blah
>
> ```
>    code code
> ```
>
> **[Reply to Answer 1]**
>   Hi @person1,
>   Thanks for your answer, it it helpful but does not quite solve my problem, but it does allow me to change my code to:
>
> ```
>    code code
> ```
>
> **[Reply to comment 1]**
>   Hi @person2,
>   Thanks for your comment, it it helpful but does not quite solve my problem, but it does allow me to change my code to:
>
> ```
>    code code
> ```
>
> **[Reply to Answer 2]**
>   Hi @person1,
>   Thanks for your answer, it it helpful but does not quite solve my problem, but it does allow me to change my code to:
>
> ```
>    code code
> ```
>
> **[Reply to comment 2]**
>   Hi @person2,
>   Thanks for your answer, it it helpful but does not quite solve my problem, but it does allow me to change my code to:
>
> ```
>    code code
> ```
>
> **[Reply to Answer 3]**
>   Hi @person1,
>   Thanks for your answer, it it helpful but does not quite solve my problem, but it does allow me to change my code to:
>
> ```
>    code code
> ```
>
> **[Reply to comment 3]**
>   Hi @person2,
>   Thanks for your answer, it it helpful but does not quite solve my problem, but it does allow me to change my code to:
>
> ```
>    code code
> ```
>
> and pages and pages of this......
>
> ---
>
> and then a large postamble section offering to help anyone else stuck on similar problems, email address, personal web site addres etc

Comment: Looks like a new user that doesn't understand how to use comments. Probably best to clean up the question removing responses that don't help the question, and integrating the rest into the question without words such as "UPDATE" or "EDIT"

Comment: Damn what a mess. Let's blindly revert it to it's first state.

Comment: Also, the "solution" should really be a separate solution.  If the user won't post the solution, perhaps a community wiki?

Comment: The more I look at it, the more I'm _actually considering_ rolling back all of those edits with a message not to add answers or comments to the OP.

Comment: Oh I'm calm. I just think it's too much trouble to salvage, so I'm not touching it with a 20-foot-pole.

Comment: I have had a crack at editing it down to a single actual question.

Comment: Related: [Exit strategies for "chameleon" questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)

Comment: Beware, the code dump time sink "it doesn't work" void of endless recursive "why doesn't it work" "I did what you said" drivel overflowing your personal time stack.

Comment: Can you summarize OP's behaviour here? Having to follow the link to see what you're talking about is less than ideal and this question will probably lose most of its value if the linked question is ever deleted or the offending behaviour is fixed.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

That is not an acceptable behavior for two primary reasons:

1. Oftentimes when the OP edits their post after receiving an answer, they do so in a way that invalidates the answer. This is often done by including the answer's code in their edit, which now exposes **another** problem in the OP's code.
   The problem with this is that the user that provided the answer now gets no credit for **correctly** identifying the problem for the OP, and now their answer is obsolete.
2. The OP may leave the original question in place, but then edit their post to begin asking further follow-up questions.
   This is a problem because it breaks the "small, specific" nature of Stack Overflow's questions, and this question could now be a considered too broad.

In my opinion, both of these problems have the same solution. The OP should:

- leave their original question intact, and accept the answer that solved their initial question
- ask a **new** follow-up question, and provide a link to their previous question for context and background

Comment: I tend to allow a small amount of leeway for supplementary questions in comments, or small question adjustments to fully solve the OP's problem. Here it's subjective: some questions really merit a fresh post, of course.

Answer (score 1):

I also agree that it should not be like that. Users editing their posts need a lesson, and we could find a good meta post to link to them. We also need to tell them that they are treating SO like a forum, which is not what SO is about. So we find the last good revision and rollback. Also, from [this revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/30990576/7), we need to tell them that we do not like people putting "[SOLVED]" in their titles or questions, and should accept a good answer instead. They also should not put "[UPDATE: I put x in y.txt]", and should instead just add it in as if it was there all along.