# "What to do when someone answers" - Don't be a chameleon, don't be a vandal

Tags: feature-request, help-center

There are some people who react... poorly... when their question is answered.

Some definitions:

- Chameleon questions are those questions that just keep on changing, to cover more than the problem you just solved in your answer.
- Vandalism, in this case, refers to those people who like to edit out all the content of the post, replacing it with "I solved this" or something.
- There's also a related group of people, for whom I have no provocative name. They edit the solution into their question. Or edit the title to say "solved", usually like this: `[SOLVED]`.

Today, I encountered one of these (a vandal), and I was thinking that I should link to the [What to do when someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) Help page, but I noticed it doesn't even mention any of these behaviors.

It does mention not to leave "thank you" answers or comments. Can it also mention that the three behaviors above are not welcome either?

Comment: I'm tempted to edit this question and write `SOLVED`. ;-)

Comment: I was recently involved in a great example of this with a simple Python GUI question. The OP had a typo in the GUI library name, and was trying to draw a rectangle directly in a window instead of in a canvas in the window. Before I'd submitted my answer 2 bad answers appeared; one just corrected the typo, the other had bizarre code containing several fatal errors. A minute or so later the OP posted comments on all 3 answers saying his question was bad & asking us to delete our answers so he could delete his question.

Comment: (cont) The question wasn't great, but it could help future readers so he was told that it's not good to delete a question if it has a decent answer. He then vandalized the question. After that edit was rolled back & he was told not to self-vandalize he then suggested an edit to vandalize my answer! After that was rejected he chameleoned his question (& its title) to ask how to open 2 windows. After a mod intervened the OP finally accepted my answer. :)

Comment: #3: "ignoramus". Editing an answer into the question and/or adding `SOLVED` to the title is the preferred way of indicating a question is answered in online forums (presumably, so an interested party does not have to scroll through to find the answer). However, SO does not work like that. Which could have been quickly noticed by a brief inspection of existing question/answer pairs.

Comment: Regarding chameleon questions, [related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297706/using-so-as-a-chatboard)

Comment: I suggest "rhetorical" to describe a question that (after editing) contains its own answer.

Comment: I'd propose a slightly different tack: add a new "What _not_ to do when someone answers" page, and move and/or elaborate on the existing "don't leave thank-you answers or comments" on that new page. This would be consistent with the existing "on-topic" and "off-topic" pages for questions, would give more space (if needed) to adequately explain the "don'ts", and most important would ensure that when the link is offered, it's clear what content is being shared (if there's just one page, people will most likely just look at the "do's" and think to themselves, "well, I did all that so I'm golden")

Comment: In the case of "people who like to edit out all the content of the post, replacing it with "I solved this" or something", I sometimes suspect homework that they didn't want their teacher to find out about.

Comment: related: [How to deal with constant changing questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252113/839601)

Comment: The last category strikes me as different in nature. They are trying to do something good, but they do so incorrectly, likely because of norms established on other sites. They don't really *deface* the content or mistreat other users; they just put information we do want posted in the wrong place. These are much more likely to be well intentioned rather than selfish actions.

Answer (score 66):

I agree with this request.

I'd like to add that the vandalism / edits can easily be reverted: Just roll back the post. Behaviour like that is not accepted on SO.
Chameleon posts are a little more tricky. Sometimes, the edits *do* add value. If they don't, they could be rolled back, also.

Comment: Seconded...or thirded technically at this point.

Comment: Chameleon posts and edits that add value are separate issues. An edit that adds value can either do so while retaining the essence of the original question, or do so *and* fundamentally change the question at the same time. It's not difficult to tell them apart.

Comment: @BoltClock: I can only agree :-)

Comment: I think the dividing line between useful edits and chameleon questions is:  Did the edit produce a more specific or more clear version of the original question, or did it turn an already specific(-ish) question into a _completely different_ specific question?

Comment: "Sometimes, the edits do add value": roll them back anyway and let the OP clean up the mess.

Answer (score 35):

The text added to the Help Center article should read:

**Please do *not* change your question after you have gotten an answer.** Improvements such as grammar and formatting corrections are fine but your edits should not invalidate existing answers. If you need to ask a new question, create a new post.

**Please do *not* delete the content of your question.** This is considered vandalism. Questions posted to Stack Overflow are meant to be helpful to future visitors.

**Please do *not* edit the answer into the question.** Questions and answers are meant to be separate. Once you mark an answer as accepted the site places that answer at the top of the list.

**Please do *not* add "SOLVED" to the question or its title.** The site already indicates that your question has been solved when you mark an answer as accepted.

---

This was written to match the existing format of the last paragraph at [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Although even minor tweaks to more than just grammar, spelling, and formatting can be reasonable: clarifying the problem, simplifying the problem case, and so on can, in principle, be perfectly acceptable.

Comment: The phrasing of the first item is misleading and based on a misconception. It is perfectly acceptable to edit question to clarify what is being asked as @Nathan mentions. Invalidating an answer of someone who guessed wrong shouldn't prevent a user from fixing their post.

Comment: *after you have gotten an answer* may be acceptable American but it is exceptionally inelegant in English.

Comment: And *after you have received an answer* is fine in both!