# How many times can a user increase the input of his question?

Tags: discussion, edits, specific-question

I recently answered a question at this link: [Extract postcards from a scanned document using opencv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49981538/extract-postcards-from-a-scanned-document-using-opencv/49983963#49983963)

The user asked a quick method to identify postcards in scans. After a first reply, I tuned the paramenter in order to identify a new image he asked for. Now he's asking again a new tuning on 2 other images.
My question is: for how long is legitimate to ask (increasing the input) before assign the mark as correct?

Comment: "But if you want some more challenge...".  No thank you.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/144883

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant, I surely know there are a lot of different ways to avoid gently this behavior. My question was more oriented in asking if there's any rule. As far as I get from your link, it seems the answer is no...

Comment: Ideally, you explain in your answer how it works to that the OP can do it himself the next time. Some people are too lazy to learn or to try - and then you can turn down further requests with a good conscience! OTOH if the OP isn't able to apply what you provide, it's perfectly good to edit your answer to provide more information.

Comment: See also [What is a help vampire?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258206)

Comment: As long as the edits are on topic with the original question I don't see any limit. It's your choice whether you will add more information to your answer or leave it to someone else to provide an answer. Further - remember that OP is **not required** to mark a question as correct.

Comment: also: ["What to do when someone answers" - Don't be a chameleon, don't be a vandal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/332820/839601)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the asker is just adding more examples without fundamentally changing the question, **there's no strict limit** on how many times they can do that.

However, if they do this more than maybe 1-2 times: (that's 1-2 edits, not 1-2 more examples)

- Their question might be too broad or underspecified (or their question *was* too broad or underspecified, but is no longer) or
- Any solution presented might be too specific to the examples instead of answering the more general question

In this case I'd probably say their question is on the edge of being too broad (but probably fine).