# User unaccepts answer because he adds more requirements to the question

Tags: discussion, unaccepted-answer

I recently saw an answer of mine being unaccepted. No big deal I though, there probably is a better answer now. When I went to look at the question I saw that the OP commented on my answer with additional requirements that were not mentioned in his question.

Personally I frown upon such behaviour, and left a comment to OP to better ask this as a new question, whilst possibly linking to the current question to provide background insights.

Was this the best course of action?

Comment: yes you approached this correctly, any new requirements for a question should be posted as a new question and if the old question provides context then a link to it should be included too

Comment: related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332820/what-to-do-when-someone-answers-dont-be-a-chameleon-dont-be-a-vandal

Comment: Did OP only comment the new requirements or also updated/changed the question?

Comment: I'd also VTC the question as unclear (and possibly downvote) since it isn't clear what question the OP is looking to get answered

Comment: Looks like you asked him to accept the answer, and he complied, that makes it a lot harder to make your case.  Just ignore and move on.

Comment: @HansPassant, I indeed commented along those lines, as he was a new user. For clarity here is my complete comment: Happy to help. If an answer on a question is helpfull to you you can let others know by upvoting (clicking the up arrow) and/or accepting (clicking the checkmark) an answer. Accepting an answer on your own question will gain you some reputation as well.

Comment: @AndréKool, OP did not edit his question. He only commented on my answer.

Comment: @Luuklag _He only commented_... in which case I would flag the comment as no longer needed and move on. Your answer could still help other users if not OP

Comment: Perhaps to add: I could update my answer to accomodate for his new requirements, but I feel that doing so would be to feed the vampire, or chameleon.

Comment: If the request is minor, and the OP has not checked/unchecked as Answer, I'll sometimes edit the Answer and leave be. But cases such as you describe, I do as you did. New users (as long as they're still around) tend to accept the guidance (in my experience in the VBA tags).

Comment: Related: [Exit strategies for “chameleon questions”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions).

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. But regarding Chameleon'ing I still have good faith in the OP. It is his first question here, and my answer most likely just presented a new problem when more data was entered and he encountered an exceptional datapoint. I flagged his comment for removal and I'll probably just wait some time and perhaps edit my answer or see if he asks a new question.

Comment: In some way the meta effect kicked in I believe ;)