# Update the answer completely or include the desired answer?

Tags: discussion

I came across a question on Stack Overflow where the OP is asking a different question later on.

It's a little difficult to explain, so bear with me. A user has asked an incomplete question to which I answered, now that the user sees the answer he realises the there are missing parts of the question and tells me so. The answer with the new info should be completely different than the previously provided one. So should I edit the answer to include the correct/desired answer or completely remove the old answer and only include the new one?

Ideally I should edit the question accordingly and update the answer, which makes it sensible. However what if I am a user without edit privileges?

Comment: Ideally you should put the question on hold if you know it's incomplete.  This presents the situation you're in right now and removes ambiguity on what to do should the OP update their question.

Comment: @Makoto Hmm... I see. Still how can I have the privilege to put the question on hold when I can't even edit the question to correct it?

Comment: @Abbas You can flag for closure even if you can't vote to close.  But more importantly you can still refrain from answering questions you believe merit closure, rather than providing answers that don't answer the question.  Help the OP clarify the question such that it is a good question and doesn't merit closure before answering it.

Comment: @Servy Got it! So a basic user has no means to complete the question his/herself? All he can do is guide the OP to correct the question themselves.

Comment: @Abbas That's going to depend on the specifics of the question, and whether or not anyone other than the author is actually able to fix whatever problems it has.  Sometimes they will be able to, sometimes they won't.

Comment: @Servy So given that a user *can* do any of these actions should he immediately do them (whichever applies) or give the OP chance to correct it himself?

Comment: @Abbas If you're able to correct a questions problems, by all means, do so.  Most problematic questions can only be fixed by the author though, as there is missing information only they know.

Comment: @Servy I understand! Now what should I do to the answer? Completely remove the old text or Edit the answer to include the new answer?

Comment: @Abbas You should focus on fixing the question.  Until the question is improved, there are no good solutions for an answer.

Comment: see also: [“What to do when someone answers” - Don't be a chameleon, don't be a vandal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/332820/839601)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you know the question is incomplete, and you know that any answers that address the current question are likely to be red herrings later on, you should vote to close the question.

This is ostensibly what the closing process is for. Once the question is fixed and properly triangulated, it can be reopened.

Answer (score 2):

> A user has asked an incomplete question to which I answered, now that the user sees the answer he realises the there are missing parts of the question and tells me so.

It's not quite clear whether

1. You knew before answering that the question was incomplete, or
2. It only became apparent after you answered, in subsequent exchanges with the OP, that the question was incomplete

In situation #1, as has been covered, it's best not to answer the question at all. Vote to close as unclear, comment to say what's missing, etc.

In situation #2, it can be tricky. Questions are not supposed to be moving targets. If it's a smallish change, you can edit your answer to accommodate it, but if — as you've indicated — it's a big change, and the previous question and answer make sense and are useful, the best thing is to tell the OP that their new question is exactly that: A new question. It should be posted separately and answered separately.

Comment: Thanks, the situation I faced was 2, where the revised question demanded a completely new answer and the old one became unrelated. I'm not sure asking the OP to post a new question where a 1 or 2 line edit (on his part) would do the job would be the best course. Perhaps I should add a link to the question it self in the question here to make the situation clear?

Comment: @Abbas - No need (but probably no harm, either), I think the general guidance is clear: Accommodate it if it's reasonable to do so, suggest posting a new question if it isn't reasonable to do so. :-)

Comment: Strangely enough no one has made any suggestions on keeping the old answer or not. As I said earlier it doesn't make sense for the OP to create a new question but what should I do? Remove the old question and only post the relative stuff? Or keep the old answer which is unhelpful to the revised question or the OP and add the new info?

Comment: For now I have posted the revised answer in the comments while discussing the situation with the OP.