# Update question before bounty end

Tags: support, questions, bounty, editing-help

I've posted a question with a bounty, and the bounty ends in two days. By doing research, I have focused the problem on a less wide aspect, but I still do not know the definite answer.

Should I just edit the question to add the new info? Is there something else I should do to avoid being unfair in some way?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A bounty is basically advertising for your question to make it more likely to get an answer. If you've found new information that will help answer your question, adding it will make your question easier to answer, so it's serving the same purpose as a bounty. So it's not unfair at all to add it, you're just making the question even more likely to be answered.

Of course, if you had found this information before placing the bounty, it would have been even better because you would have been advertising a better question to start with, but there is nothing wrong with improving your question once the bounty is placed. The concern you might want to watch out for, though, is making a [chameleon question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/332820/7795130), that is, when you morph your question into a new question through edits. But if you're clarifying the same original question, that's fine.

Comment: The primary issue is that the edit should not invalidate answers. For example, by making them wrong; making it such that they are answering the wrong question; or making them to now be incompletely answering the question. That one, or more, answers are invalidated is the criteria that is normally used to determine if the question has been changed too much.