# Methods to remedy a Chameleon Question and teach the OP

Tags: discussion

**Source:** [How to replace "e1" to "a", "e9" to "b", ie "a9" to "b", "b1" to "a"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53680694/how-to-replace-e1-to-a-e9-to-b-ie-a9-to-b-b1-to-a/53696737?noredirect=1#comment94327165_53696737)

**How to properly remedy this chameleon question (plus lost "accept answer") while teaching the user how to properly handle extension**

## Background

For the last week, I have been working with this user to solve this interesting question. Sure, the question wasn't up to the best quality, but the user is fairly new. After some clarification in the comments, I created a solution and posted the answer. The user was very pleased and I thought that was the end of this post.

## Issue

After I answered the question, the user asked me how to do something else. Most likely due to possible language difficulties, I didn't fully understand what they wanted me to clarify. I asked for clarification and found out that the user had...

- Changed the title
- Replaced old code with my "correct" code
- Updated the question to ask an extension question based off of the new code.

This seems to be something that would be looked down on, right?

#### Remedies

1. Rollback the last edit.

   - This seems to be a pure "[Chameleon](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332820/what-to-do-when-someone-answers-dont-be-a-chameleon-dont-be-a-vandal)"
2. The OP can do one of the following...

   - Explain the issue in the comments.
   - Ask a new question.
   - Create an "EDIT" section on the bottom of the old question explaining issues during extending my new code.
   - (Any other idea?)
3. What about the removed "Accepted Answer"?

## Notes

I can see they don't know the best ways of posting questions and giving extra information. However, they have been fairly responsive and me requesting them to change something. However, it now seems like I could come off as too "pushy" as I am always suggesting them to do it some other way.

Comment: General advice: Don't engage too much which that kind of VLQ questions. In the long term it turns out not to be worth it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes, I agree, but the user is showing an ability to learn how to do things right. They are not hopeless right now

Comment: They'll probably better learn from questions closed than proposed edits. In general: _"Don't edit turds"_ might apply.

Comment: see also: [Exit strategies for “chameleon questions”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130630/165773)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That seems like ideas that thrown around before StackOverflow became more nicer. I remember being a new user here, and I hated it. I'm not going to be "that guy" unless this user shows resistance. But thanks to gnat, I have some solutions. Don't worry, if the user is resisting, then I will not waste more time

Comment: downvote and move on

Comment: @ChristopherRucinski Unfortunately there seems to be no other way than just the seemingly harsh. Downvote/Close vote. Leaving comments or edits doesn't lead to any good, OP's are responsible to create good questions themselves in 1st place, not to mention that they're already given all the in depth knowledge they need in the help center.

Comment: @ChristopherRucinski _"like ideas that thrown around before StackOverflow became more nicer."_ My first questions applied here were kinda too unspecific, and I quickly noticed that. As soon as I started to contribute at the side of answering it went better for me tho. Meanwhile I rarely ask or answer, but just try to moderate keeping in mind the FAQ goal nature of the site.

Comment: Are we to the point where, if a new user hasn't shown that they don't want to learn, and someone wants to help them, we shut them down? No one is forcing us to get the user to improve. But if Chris wants to do it.... Why not let them, why shut them down because *we* have been burned by ungrateful users? Before I got jaded about my moderation, I saw *some* users willing to improve. What if the author of the linked post is one of these?...

Comment: We aren't being nicer by lowering our quality standards; all we're doing is setting up new users for future failure.  Users are responsible for their own actions.  We don't have to be rude, but we *do* have to maintain our standards, so that *everyone else* after the asker gets good help.

Comment: @Patrice: "*But if Chris wants to do it.... Why not let them, why shut them down because we have been burned by ungrateful users?*" Because it gives the impression that these sort of things are expected/encouraged on SO. Regardless of the user's intent, these questions are bad questions and we shouldn't want them here. Nor should any user expect a week's worth of effort out of other users.

Comment: @Nicol but, isn't comments exactly for that? I agree that no one should be expected to give this. But if some of our users want to, why not? We could have answered here with "next time, take it to chat, engage rapidly, help them fix their question then answer". What he's getting here is "don't engage, don't try to help, just close and move on".

Comment: @Patrice: "*but, isn't comments exactly for that?*" Yes, to ask for something specific. But if you have to cajole information out of someone through several back-and-forth comments, that's not functional.

Comment: @Patrice Are we to the point where, if a long-time user has expressed a hard-won opinion of the proper course of action based on years of experience, we shut them down? No one is forcing the user to downvote and move on, but if they want to, why not let them? :P

Comment: @HereticMonkey I am the first one who says new users usually don't want to be helped. But here we have a user who didn't showcase such a non-willingness. I have no issue with making it clear to "hey, a lot of users won't be like this one, be careful so you don't get bit". I am just disappointed that we aren't even giving the chance to offer help. We are moving into a transactional SO 100%, without giving the chance of people who want to help to actually help. I just think our response here could have been slightly tempered.

Comment: @Nicol I feel, again, that our answer could have been different. What would have been bad here about "comments aren't for such a long back and forth. Next time move it to chat, get all you need to make the question good, then ask the user to edit, then answer". We are really moving to a place where "if you don't know how to ask your first question, tough luck, we don't want people to help you make it better". That's the only thing I find disappointing.

Comment: @Patrice Temper it with your own answer then. That's how `discussion` questions are supposed to work, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Roll the question back to the point before where it changed into another question. Then tell the OP not to do that again, that if they want to ask a new question, they have a button to do that.

Also, it should be noted that your attempt to work with the user is likely what made them think this was a forum-like environment where they get to change their posts however they want. This is one reason why we discourage this kind of interaction. If a question isn't answerable, then by all means, explain why. But you should not expend extraordinary effort working with a user like this. It gives them the wrong impression of how the site is supposed to work and ultimately hurts everyone.

Comment: I can fully understand your points. I was starting to think that I was a new user again, which is also why people will try to answer questions and interact with new users as I have been. It's a double-edged sword and goes both ways. I have noted your points and will make sure the user doesn't expect this in the future.

Comment: _"If a question isn't answerable"_ - this sums it up all too well. This is the reason for the first few days of a question's closure it says `[On Hold]` instead of `[Closed]` to let OP know that they can still fix the questions issues and make it clear. The best thing to do is just close the question and let OP get his stuff together - it's much easier to reopen a question than to close it - _(reopen queue only has ~100 questions compared to the 9k+ close)_

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs I don't see how this comment applies the question at all.  The question was answerable. After a small clarification in the comments, I fully understood what the user wanted, and answered it. The answer was accepted. Then the question was changed, and my answer was un-accepted.

Comment: @ChristopherRucinski My comment wasn't an attempt to answer your issue specifically, but to build on the broader point from Nicol's answer: _"If a question isn't answerable..."_.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs well only **that small part** of Nicol Bolas's answer is wrong. It is still answerable, but should be asked in a different manner and he verified that a new question is problably the best idea. Note: I think Nicol meant "if and only if"

Comment: For your point, @ChristopherRucinski - I feel it would be completely justified to close the question as 'Too Broad' if he's used the same question to ask 5 different questions.

Answer (score 14):

Here's where the issue really came up:

> For the last week

You engaged a user **for almost an entire week** on their problem.

Irrespective of how new or how inexperienced anyone is, **this is not an appropriate use of the platform.**  If the OP insists on doing this, it's most efficient and expedient to downvote their question and **move on** from it.  Do not spend so much time helping one OP that they feel that it's acceptable to use the site in this fashion.

Comment: Correct. I did spend a week. However, I was learning **how to** solve this issue for most of that time as it was related to a future project I wanted to work on before but didn't know how to do it. I now know possible ways to solve my own new project. So the 1 week of help is a mischaracterization. However, I do understand your last sentence. Fully noted!