# What should I do when a user appropriates my answer in his question?

Tags: discussion

I've just answered a question, my answer was close to be working (a detail was missing). Then the question poster has appropriated my answer and copied it in his question.

What should we do when this happens? It causes the answer to be somewhat unrelated to the question as it repeats the same thing and the question becomes "Why this answer doesn't work?" (referring to an answer of the question itself)

The question: ['YT' is not defined - Youtube Player API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67343720/yt-is-not-defined-youtube-player-api/67491085#67491085)

Comment: rollback and read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377812/methods-to-remedy-a-chameleon-question-and-teach-the-op among other Q/A's for the same topic.

Comment: This isn't about someone appropriating your answer, it's about editing a question that invalidates the answers. If a question is edited *after* it has started receiving answers that causes those answers to no longer be relevant it should normally be rolled back; as the answers are invalidated and means that they (in conjunction with the question) are no longer useful. If the OP has a *new* question off the back of the answer they received they should post a new question. If it's because they have asked a XY Problem, then they should post a new question about X.

Comment: Don't jump to conclusions - it seems like the OP acted in good faith, albeit misguided (it looks suspiciously like they thought they should update their question with your code that they couldn't get working the first time around) - seems like everything's resolved now

Comment: Well I did what you suggested. Reverted the question and explained why

Comment: @GuerricP - ok, this was fast :) I wanted to add a "human" note from me: this is the closest thing I've found that has clear guidance for OPs in case of chameleon questions. P.s. Jeanne, if you happen to chance on this - do you have a more suitable dupe target?

Comment: Live with it, users take the answers and delete their questions. It is part of SO live

Comment: @nbk that's a fatalistic point of view 

Comment: Note as well, @GuerricP , what you can also do is open the revisions page of the question, select the edit option for the revision you want to roll back to, and then (instead) leave a note in the edit summary rather than the comments; that means that the Rollback will be noted and why in the same place and can't be later deleted as comments are second place citizens. For example as I did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/174582/revisions). I didn't change anything in the body of the revision, but edited, and then added a summary. I find this method quite clean.