# I was told I would only get the correct answer if I accepted the incorrect one first

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, etiquette

I was just wondering how I should deal with people like this.

I asked a question, and was given an answer that dealt with an image taken off a website, whilst my problem involved an image I have stored on my computer.

I commented this, and politely asked for clarification.

I was then told I could only get clarification if I accepted the answer that didn't work. When I refused, the answer was deleted and I was told I didn't deserve an answer:

> i delete my answer. You dont deserve solution. I gave you answer with exact image processing steps that works on the image you posted, but since you cant upload image into python script and integrate it with my script, you dont consider it answer. Also you propably didnt get, that my script downloaded your image, and processed it. Did you even tried to run the script?

I know any answer has taken someone time, and I'm grateful for that time. I can't help but feel I've done something wrong here. Am I at fault?

How do I deal with this kind of thing?

[Link to question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54261255/pytesseract-cant-read-text-off-very-simple-image)

**Edit:**

To clear up some things said in comments:

1. I knew how to open a PIL image from disk, but didn't know how to open an OpenCV one, they are different.
2. Looking back at my question, and reading some of the comments on here, I believe it was clear from my question that I wanted to open the image from disk, as I wrote `Image.open(IMAGE FILE)`
3. I realise that this question could have been asked better, and for that I apologise (I've been using this site for less than a month). However, I feel it is unfair to say that my comment was asking a 'completely different question', when it was really just asking for a CV2 version of what was already in my question's code
4. I needed basically just one more line of code, and so asked in the comments. I realise now that I should've done my own research instead. Again, I apologise for this. What I definitely wasn't expecting in answer to my comment, however, was abuse. Especially from someone who has been a member of this site for over two years.

Comment: That user went from "if it helps, select it as answer" to "Well first select it as answer" in 20 minutes flat. I think that says a lot more about them than it does you.

Comment: Well he went from I have problem recognizing image to how to load an image in python script...

Comment: While this question about particular comment is of reasonably quality (also likely duplicate of "is it ok to request accepts"), the question you've linked to does not show why existing answers do not  solve the problem ("Yeah, that still didn't work for me" - is not one), and based on your comments it is way to broad as you need help not with just image processing itself but also (at least) with file reading part. You may want to improve linked question or find better example...

Comment: ... note that linked question has zero indication that " whilst my problem involved an image I have stored on my computer" - there is absolutely no reason why answer should include such information (should answer also includes FTP, HTTPS, raw TCP reading examples?). Please check out "chameleon questions" topics on Meta to avoid such cases in the future (like https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332820/what-to-do-when-someone-answers-dont-be-a-chameleon-dont-be-a-vandal).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov What you say is supported by the fact, that another person is trying to answer OP same way as I did.

Comment: IMO neither party in this is blamelss, but yours was the first error that motivated another person to a negative reaction: neither the original nor the edited question mention anything about needing to load the image from a local source...

Comment: ...Stack Overflow is not a typical forum where things are discussed and developed in an exchange - it's a Q&A site: the question should contain all relevant information and concentrate on one aspect. Your question does that, but then after someone has done the work and answered the original question you demand more. That's not OK on this site. Yes, the comment wasn't ideally phrased, but it's also not correct to specify additional requirements *after the fact*. A new requirement should be in a new question.

Comment: @hegash it doesn't matter how you might have been at fault - it doesn't condone the other user's behaviour; I'm sorry and embarrassed for the community that you were treated that way, even if you weren't a new contributor. You get them in ever walk of life; just move on. If you receive continued harassment, report it to a moderator.

Comment: After some comments from community memebers here I realized that the way I handled situation was not the best way and I will be in the future more careful. However, I am amazed at the amount of upvotes to OP, that mislead everybody with lying title(I provided answer that was correct) and quite untrue description of what happened.

Comment: @Martin SO/Meta.SO have similar rules for questions and voting on them - question must be on topic (preferably practical) and contain all information necessary to answer. This question is perfectly fine as standalone question and can be upvoted as such. The topic covered by the question is relatively common and happens often enough so question likely will be useful for future users (which again calls for upvotes). Now OP used somewhat questionable *example* of the problem but it does not mean "lying in the title" - I think comment already cover the fact that OP should not have ...

Comment: ...put themselves into position to receive such reply from you. You also provided *very well received* answer (please re-read comments on you answer if you don't feel so) which got negative score because *as answer to this question* it is not what we want to see as advice for user's behavior. Votes are for on-topic-ness and correctness but not for style. (It is very hard to express "your post is of good quality but seriously bad recommendation" - I appreciate your efforts to understand and explain the case and hope it will help you with future contributions on SO and Meta).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov thank you for your insight

Comment: @Cindy Meister: The code that's provided in the question was right there all along, and it says, very clearly, `Image.open(IMAGE FILE)`. I get that that's not the same as spelling out that a local file is *required*, but the *least* an answer could do was follow that instead of... trying to load an image off of an i.stack.imgur.com URL? This just brings me back to my age-old rant of "Why provide code in a question if it's just going to get ignored?"

Comment: @BoltClock Its interesting, how you defend it. The fact that he already has there function for opening local files proves, that he had no idea what he is doing and I was there only as freelancer. Its like someone asks you to help him solve differential equitations and after you solve it, he ask you if you can also explain him what equals 1+1. What I did was bad and overreaction, but its because I was quite offended

Comment: @Martin: I don't know about you, but when I answer questions any divergence from the question takes extra, *conscious* effort and I like to save my energy where possible. Diverging from a question unnecessarily is a waste of my energy and can cause unnecessary confusion for the asker and other readers. I do get your frustration with that sort of thing, and I'm glad that you acknowledge that you may not have handled this as well as you could have.

Comment: If the only problem with his answer was that it loads the image from the internet, that means the rest of his answer is correct, right? Is there a reason you can't just use the code he provided, and change the line that loads the image from the internet to a line that loads it from disk? That seems like a trivial change to me. I'm not saying he reacted appropriately in the end, he didn't. But your question was about how to process the image, so as long as his code does the processing part correctly, I would say it's the correct answer, no?

Comment: @DarthFennec yes, now that I've figured out how to open the image, the rest of the code does work (not as well as one of the other answers though, which is why I accepted that one). The ironic thing is that if he hadn't reacted how he did, he would have gotten the 'accepted' he so badly wanted

Comment: At this point, there's no reason to keep this argument going.  You both realized what happened, and how to rectify it.  Chalk it up to a learning experience for everybody, and move on.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

- If the discussion has indicated your question is unclear, clarify it. Make sure nobody else will attempt to answer it in the same way that was originally unhelpful to your particular situation.
- If there are rude comments, flag them so that a moderator can delete them. I believe that comment was unfriendly, or unkind and I flagged it as such, the offending comment has now been deleted.
- If such comments continue to appear from the same person, use a custom flag and explain the situation so that a moderator can take appropriate action.
- Otherwise just move on, if your question is clear enough someone else will answer it.

Answer (score 24):

I'm trying not to be condescending (I've been there), but I think both the asker and answerer must learn more how to use the site (there's good hope for this given that both parties posted on meta), regardless of their technical skills.

- The asker is provided with a solution. It doesn't work for them "out of the box" (needs some rework with reading the input image), but the example seems self-contained, and gets votes: commenting is okay, but image/character recognition doesn't work all the time; it depends on the data (and maybe the shown image has been resized/processed in a way that makes OCR programs fail). Maybe the asker isn't ready to get a good answer.

  Sometimes you have to learn in books *before* you ask questions on Stack Overflow. And here comes the follow-up question in comments...  *How would I do this for an image stored on my computer?*. This is clearly a different question, unrelated to image recognition. Don't ask the question; search by yourself.
- The answerer made a good technical answer, but should just ignore the follow-up requests or comment: "this is a new question, sorry". But *never* tell to accept the answer so the follow-up question can be answered. Acceptance is cool, but sometimes you have to live without it.

  Votes (global evaluation by a community) are way more important than accepted answer (biased evaluation by an individual who wants their problem solved). Sometimes you have to let it go.

And an answerer should not delete an answer just to punish the asker. Note that 10K+ users can *see* deleted answers & revisions. The Internet never forgets.

Comment: I think your comments to the asker need to be reworded slightly. To say, "It didn't work for them," is an exaggeration. The asker's complaint was that it used a web image (the example image from the question) instead of loading from disk, even though the question demonstrated that the asker knows how to load the image from disk already. The asker is demanding a drop in script that requires no changes. That is unacceptable on SO; we expect askers to be able to grasp the important concepts from an answer and combine them with specifics of their situation. Doing so is fundamental to programming.

Comment: @jpmc26 My question demonstrated I knew how to load a PIL image from disk, not an OpenCV image. As you say, my question already implied I wanted to load the image from disk, so I'm not sure why the answer showed how to load an image from the web

Comment: @hegash because I cant solve your problem without having an image . You change small parameter and pytesseract output is again empty (I do not know, if uploading the image in SO change quality or resolution). Also you specificaly said 'Here is the image'. Loading image into PIL and change it to cv2 is the smallest thing and this question is answered everywhere.

Comment: @hegash Because they are separate tasks requiring different information to answer. SO might provide answers to both, but not in the same question. It is your responsibility to take the how-to of each task and combine them into a fully functional program. SO rarely provides code that works on copy/paste. It provides help with working out little, individual pieces that can be sewn into the fabric of a bigger program.

Comment: "And an answerer should not delete an answer just to punish the asker. Note that 10K+ users can see deleted answers & revisions" Not just that, but we can vote to undelete them in this case, too. Once it's posted, it's no longer purely up to the poster's whims whether the post lives or dies.

Comment: I do not want to disrespect you, but you already reedited your answer several times because you didn't 'studied the case' properly. You started from - solution didn't work - - solution may have worked -  to - solution didnt work out of the box-. Please make some research and so we  finally end up with -> solution worked as Answer required but....

Comment: @Martin Now that is rather silly. The core of the answer has remained the same through each edit. There have just been a couple of minor (though important) clarifications. This answer is fair and even-handed, discussing the problems with behavior on each side of the conflict. Jean is absolutely right; there are problems on both sides here, as is usually the case in a conflict. If you're going to argue that hegash should be able to extract the important details for their situation out of your answer, then you should do the same with this one, even if a couple of minor details were a little off.

Answer (score 9):

It's right to flag for moderator attention in this situation.

This case is more than just run-of-the-mill badgering of an asker to accept an answer (although even that is obnoxious). Here the answerer offered you a quid-pro-quo: you accept his answer, and he gives you help with your next problem. That's voting fraud, worthy of moderator action against the user. We want people to cast their votes and accept answers *based upon the merits of the post*, and someone offering to help you with a separate problem in exchange for accepting his answer corrupts the system, just as surely as if they'd tried to induce you to accept their answer by offering to vote on your posts in exchange (or, more fancifully, by offering you money or some real-world reward). Such quid-pro-quo is not okay, and I'd think that an offer of it merits an annotation on the user's account.

(It would also normally merit a mod message, but in this case the user in question has already had the problem with their behaviour explained to them via the responses to this Meta question, and [seems to appreciate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379138/told-i-would-only-get-correct-answer-if-i-accepted-incorrect-one/379147#comment663846_379138) that this was a dumb and improper thing to have done, which is good.)

Comment: I agree with the general tone of this (it's wrong and flag-worthy) but "moderator action against the user" seems quite overblown here. It's much more appropriate in this situation for a moderator to simply remove offensive/unfriendly comments. *Maybe* send a moderator message to both, but certainly not to take action *against* the user; we don't ban people at the first round-about suggestion of some behavior that might be considered voter fraud.

Comment: @TylerH A mod message is precisely the action I'm imagining - I didn't intend the phrase "action against" to imply anything more than that. Maybe I was a soft child, but to my sensibilities getting a telling off from teacher *was* a punishment, and I guess that's the mindset from which I used the phrase "moderator action against the user" here.

Comment: Gotcha. I understand the phrasing 'taking action against' to be adversarial in tone, e.g. pitting the moderator (as is their job) 'against' the user by taking some such action. I view moderator messages as informative/corrective (thus "with" or "for" the user rather than "against") rather than punitive/combative.