# Can I ask someone to accept my answer to a question on hold if they found it useful?

Tags: discussion, answers

I answered a question that was later put on hold due to asking for a recommendation, but despite being the only answer currently there, and (in my opinion) being a suitable answer to the question being asked, it was never accepted.

I admit I used an answer provided by someone else in a different question. I linked to their answer, and told them I used it by commenting on their answer and providing a link to my question.

I did change their code a little bit to make it runnable without anything extra other than import statements. I also switched the text printed to what the question-asker used in their code example.

*Is it all right for me to ask them to accept my answer if they found it useful?*

Comment: "Is it alright for me to ask them to accept my answer if they found it useful?" -- No it's not.  You will also want to beware of the [Meta Effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect) where asking a question on meta about a stackoverflow question brings additional attention to the question, possibly positive attention and possibly negative attention.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks. I noticed my answer already has a down-vote for some reason.

Comment: Kinda related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379138/i-was-told-i-would-only-get-the-correct-answer-if-i-accepted-the-incorrect-one-f

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's never all right to ask people to accept your answer regardless of whether the question is open or closed.

While the acceptance mark is useful - it shows the answer that the OP thinks helped them the most - it's not a requirement on the OP to select an answer to receive the tick.

If you answer a question you should do so because you think you know the answer and with no expectation of reward - either votes from other users or the acceptance from the OP. If you start asking for votes then it's more than likely going to backfire as others may well see it as demanding.

Comment: I've seen a number of answers that clearly resolve the question posed—whether my answers or others'—but for whatever reason, often new users, the one asking the question does not accept an answer. The question remains public but there's no indication that any answer solved their problem. Accepted answers is typically one of the main indicators that help direct people to valuable solutions. What's the harm to remind someone to select the answer that best meets their needs? Also, what's wrong with formulating quality answers for the thrill of helping out, as indicated by accepts and up-votes?