# Is it acceptable to downvote an answer because the poster of the answer asked for it to be accepted?

Tags: discussion, answers, downvotes

I am curious whether I should down-vote an otherwise adequate answer purely because the person who posted it requested that their answer be accepted, which I recently learned isn't allowed here.

I flagged his comment, but the question-asker had already seen it and accepted his answer. Now, I can't see his comment any more. I'm not completely sure if other people can't though.

[The Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54382835/netbeans-javafx-cant-select-main-class)

Comment: As far as I know it's completely acceptable to ask the OP to accept an answer if it worked for them.

Comment: @TheWanderer Well, [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379461/can-i-ask-someone-to-accept-my-answer-to-a-question-on-hold-if-they-found-it-use) is where I learned differently. Also, my flag was accepted.

Comment: [Here's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88535/asking-for-someone-to-accept-your-answer) and MSE discussion, that's a duplicate of an MSE discussion, both saying the opposite. It depends on _how_ you say it. If it's a comment made before the OP could even have a chance of seeing the answer, then it might be a problem.

Comment: [Here's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262209/are-we-allowed-to-ask-remind-the-op-to-accept-answers) an MSO discussion from 2014, so more recent. (And [here's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136833/is-it-okay-to-ask-a-user-to-accept-my-answer) a dupe of that first MSE dupe I linked).

Comment: Honestly, the only other instance I can find of someone saying it's bad is by the dupe target on your Meta question. The dupe target of _that_ one says that it's fine if the user probably doesn't know how the system works.

Comment: @TheWanderer Well, there's also the first comment in that question. Now I'm just confused.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In general, your votes should reflect the content of a post. That's a pretty simple rule that works almost all the time. Applying that rule in this case, you should vote based on the content of the answer as it stands alone, and not take into account anything the *user* behind the answer has done.

You did the right thing in flagging the comment; these are easy deletes for us (if the flag even makes it to us). Bonus points if you look at the commenter's history for stale "please-accept" requests.

Comment: But wouldn't looking at the commenter's comment history constitute *Targeting*? We already have a feature that explicitly discourages people from visiting someone's profile in order to downvote all of their crappy posts - isn't flagging also problematic?

Comment: Perhaps technically, but realistically it's a net help to the site to get rid of old comments. If you find a convenient list of stuff to flag, there's no reason not to use it - even if that list is a profile. There are some cases where we tell people to quit interacting with each other in any way, but those are few and far between. You'd know it if you were somehow flagging obsolete comments with malicious intent.

Comment: @RobertColumbia I'm sure we'll see a Twitterati claiming that sort of behaviour is "unkind" in the not-so-distant future.

Answer (score 15):

Asking to make the answer accepted has two categories in my opinion.

The first and most common is the ones that do so in order to just get the rep points.
Those users generally have lower rep points.
They do that comment in order to "steal" the answer from other answers to the same question.
The "please accept my answer" usually comes when the user feels threatened by other competing answer that is similar or better.

In that case I don't find them correct.

The other category is when there is only one answer or one answer is clearly the "one" or when OP says "thanks, this worked for me".
In those cases I find it correct to ask for the accept as it shows "this is correct", and it also shows in a search that this question has an accepted answer.
If the question is fairly new then it also shows that you don't need to "waste" yourselves on this question as it has been solved.

As I see it, it depends on how the comment was written, what the other answers looks like etc.

Comment: "If the question is fairly new then it also shows that you don't need to "waste" yourselves on this question as it has been solved." On many other sites in the network, I see people advising new posters to **not** accept an answer right away for exactly this reason - it might prevent a better answer from being posted.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery but on SO your question is pretty much gone after 30 minutes in the top tags. Weekends is usually slower and some times of the day but in general you have about 30 minutes to get your question correct if you want an answer. In my opinion waiting for a answer is not working as the question falls away too quickly on SO. If you have not got the answer you want then use the bounty. But as I see it you will not get more answers when your question is more than 30-45 minutes old, and if you get a good answer then just accept it so that others don't have to read it all for "nothing".

Comment: While this is true, I visit answered questions to upvote the worthy and cast shade on those found lacking. Woe betide those stuck with a question accepted as the answer and now cannot be deleted as in spite of suffering a withering barrage of downvotes, fixing the cone of shame firmly around their neck.

Comment: @user4581301 so do I sometimes, but in general the first 30 minutes will generate about 90% of the traffic to that question.

Comment: Not 100% convinced by your first point—it is perfectly acceptable to ask the user to "_accept an answer that helped them the most if their question was solved_, because that's what a good Stack Overflow citizen should do". A lot of users tend to ask, get an answer, and ghost without accepting, usually because they don't know there's more they _could_ be doing. As long as you are informing OP that the "accept an answer" feature exists, rather than singling out a particular answer to curry favor, it is not a problem to make this request.

Comment: @coldspeed but the people who I mention in category 1 is the ones who post "pick my answer". I flagged the same person twice within a few minutes for "pick my answer" today. Both times the comment was removed immediately. A few months ago I did the same three or four times, again within a few minutes. Again obvious category 1, they do not care there is other answers they just "pick me, pick me!". What you describe is more a category 2 as I see it.

Comment: Right, just thought that distinction was worth mentioning.