# Bad Triage Review Audit

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits, triage, specific-audit

While reviewing on the Triage queue, I failed [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25636331) today.

From my perspective, everything hinted towards an unsalvageable question, as it doesn't show any context. The question mentions a code snippet, which is not (anymore) present in it and multiple commentators indicated that the user was asking the same question over and over again.

Nevertheless, according to the audit system this question apparently "Looks ok". Am I missing the point, or is this actually a bad candidate for an audit?

Comment: Yeah, that wasn't a great question even before all the details were removed, and it's awful in its current state. Unfortunately, the audit system is automated and the question was at +6/-0 so the system assumed it was good. Blame all the people who upvoted it for some inexplicable reason.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Original post looked reasonable with some decent amount of code and information. For some reason author of the post removed most of the content on 2020-02-29 making question very confusing.

As result of being reasonable question it had +6 votes and was eligible for audit. Unfortunately audits show current version which was clearly bad. This should be fixed by now as post is collecting downvotes/close votes which will kick it out from possible audits.

I support your "unsalvageable" for vote for the post in the state you've seen it. You probably don't need to do anything about it unless you get automatic ban on next audit - that you can mention this post in your ban dispute flag.

<sub>Post is currently reverted to original state and should be out of possible "known good" audit list due to downvotes/close votes</sub>

Comment: "For some reason" I just noticed they did the same thing with a bunch of their other questions. Probably a homework problem that they didn't want to get caught asking for help on or something.

Comment: I see @JohnMontgomery is reverting all the vandalism edits.  Is that sufficient, or should a mod flag be raised to have someone send the user a warning.

Comment: @DanisFiddlingbyFirelight cases like that are thoroughly discussed here [“What to do when someone answers” - Don't be a chameleon, don't be a vandal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/332820/839601)