# After marking as duplicate, OP says they are looking for *other* solutions. Is this enough reason to reopen?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I recently encountered two questions, which I think are duplicates, (I can give the links of these questions if you want), so I marked them as such with my gold hammer.

Then, the OPs clarified that they are aware of the solutions shown in dupe targets, and are actually looking for *another solution*, that is not one of those presented in the dupe targets. For both of those dupe targets, the solution is either "it's not possible", or considered "not elegant" by the OP, so I get why they are looking for another "better" solution.

I was tempting to reopen the questions, but then I thought, if everyone used this argument,

> I've seen the dupe targets, but I don't like any of the solutions there, so I'm actually looking for solutions *other than* those in the dupe target, so this is not a duplicate.

then there would be no duplicates! Because that argument seems to work on every question...

Is "I'm looking for another solution" enough of a reason for a question to not be a duplicate?

Comment: Nah - if there's another solution, better for it to be posted on the canonical, and then the canonical can be linked to whenever the question gets asked again. Having things in one place is good.

Comment: Well, when most people's questions get closed, they have to provide a reason for _why_ they want another solution.

Comment: Common situation is the other solutions require a bit of interpretation to apply to their code....and they are wanting copy/paste solutions tailored to their more specific situation. Better justification why the dups won't work for them is typically needed

Comment: The other students have already copypasta the dupes into their own assignment submissions, and so SO minions must get to work and come up with unique answers to prevent the discovery of cheating/plagging.

Comment: I thought it was standard that OP should open another question if the previous one was closed as dupe and not satisfying enough. Now, where did I read that again...

Comment: @Clockwork: that is a good approach, if the OP can genuinely demonstrate their question requires _different_ information. But they have to do more than post a seemingly identical question with a seemingly identical answer. They need to post a question that shows the code they've tried, and explain precisely why it is that the existing solutions don't suffice. There must be enough information to provide a clear path to a single good solution to their problem, in a manner that is clearly unique, distinct from the existing questions and answers. Just wanting a different answer is insufficient.

Comment: Only if they can motivate why none of the existing solutions solves their problem satisfactorily. They must state their specific requirements and the question then becomes "how to solve X under these conditions". Basically they must at the very least define "more elegant". It's the same as if I would ask for a better answer. Better in which way?

Comment: Or to put it even shorter: If somebody simply wants more answers, then asking more often for them is not going to work.

Comment: Every time I have come across a situation where an asker edits their question to say they're not satisfied with the answers provided because of <reasons>, it is because they have either not thought enough about the problem, or do not understand it as well as the people answering: in other words, their <reasons> are spurious. (Or they are just being difficult, or are a help vampire as @MartinJames noted.) In contrast, questions where the asker lists the constraints up-front and why, generally get answered and accepted. It's the difference between helpdesk and research.

Comment: related: [“What to do when someone answers” - Don't be a chameleon, don't be a vandal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/332820/839601). Duplicate is [intended to provide an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166707/165773), "This question already has an answer here" - meaning if asker adds something new over what is provided by the already existing answer then they need to ask a new, different question

Comment: "Something better" or "something different" is not a problem that can be solved. A specific deficiency in the other solutions would need to be identified.

Comment: Re: _"do not understand it as well as the people answering"_ - this is why, unless Stack Overflow is openly seeking to be an elitist site, dupes in such situations don't work very well. The dupe system as it exists fails to provide a bridge between where the OP is (in terms of understanding) and how they might cross the learning-gap between there and the answers to _another question_ which, from their perspective, doesn't appear to bear much relation to what they are asking. This is equivalent to throwing a person in need some fishing bait instead of teaching them how to fish.

Comment: @ikegami Thank you, oh thank you for pointing out the "Quality" problem. Especially important here. And to boot, makes me think of [Robert Pirsig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_M._Pirsig) and _Zen_. Good stuff!

Comment: @MartinJames if that's the problem, the question should have been rejected in the first place - homework questions that can be copied and pasted are effectively never acceptable as questions, not because of the the plagiarism risk but because they Need More Focus. Homework is written like a laundry list of tasks.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

No, an "I want another solution" comment is absolutely not enough to re-open the question.

If you feel that there is some actual reason, you can *edit* the question first to clarify that indeed the OP has seen those existing solutions (link to them) and what exact differences/improvements are expected. Generally you need to have full editing privileges for that and have enough subject-matter knowledge to make sure that the question indeed becomes sufficiently unique to deserve re-opening.

Note that if the OP just needs a "better" solution to the exact problem shown in the duplicate, the right route is to put a bounty on the duplicate target. You can leave a comment for the OP mentioning this, or you as a user with a lot of reputation can set the bounty yourself yourself.

Alternatively you can just let OP to make an edit or put a bounty on the duplicate target. The chances of that happening are slim though and it is very unlikely that the OP would make a good enough edit to let the question qualify for reopening.

Comment: So if the title were edited into "How do I do X without «technique used in dupe»" and the text was updated with something like "this link «link to dupe here» doesn't satisfy because reason R", then it would be probably eligible for reopening?

Comment: @MCEmperor Yes. But... if the person asking the question has thought it through properly, and done their research, **they almost certainly will already have found the dupe already**. Therefore, their question will likely contain that information in the first place, so it won't ever be closed to begin with. In contrast, most cases where a question lacks that information, or the asker wants a specific solution, are ones where they haven't done research or don't properly understand the issue - in which case it is completely appropriate to close as a dupe.

Comment: That's a great point that a high-rep user can place a bounty on the dupe target effectively "on behalf of" the new user. I sometimes feel bad closing something as a duplicate of a question with really poor _answers_, even though the _question_ is clearly the same, and this makes a better compromise (as long as the bounty system actually works in attracting a new answer!)

Comment: I strongly disagree that adding a "without using the obvious technique" rider makes for a different question, in normal cases. Especially since "here's another way that doesn't use the obvious technique:" would introduce a perfectly acceptable new answer on the canonical.

Answer (score 20):

> Is "I'm looking for another solution" enough of a reason for a
> question to not be a duplicate?

No I don't think it's good enough reason.I would argue that just reopening it may not attract another solution instead it may attract same solutions which is already in the duplicate target.

Often I have observed OP does not think through the constraints of the current question properly in the first place which makes the question susceptible to be closed as duplicate. But after carefully looking at the duplicate target if OP can comeback with a distinguishing constraints which makes the question quite a bit different from the duplicate target I would be willing to reopen it after making sure that the question is edited with the constraint explained and the duplicate target is linked in the question.

Comment: I agree that the reason is not good enough, however, I just curious why to reopen a poorly asked question instead of wiping it out, rethinking it, reformatting it, and asking it again?

Comment: There is a reason why the re-open button exists. Everything should get more than one chance.Folks make mistake and we should give them ability to learn from it.

Comment: @Nick Did you miss this part? "I would be willing to reopen it **after making sure that the question is edited with the constraint explained and the duplicate target is linked in the question**."

Answer (score 14):

It's possible that the duplicates explain the principle, but the user wants their specific case answered. For instance, a common question is how to move data back and forth between a client browser and a web server. The answer is a methodology called [AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510011/how-does-ajax-work) and there are ample questions that demonstrate how to do it  (with or without a library). Yet we still have users who posit their AJAX questions, and when you close them as a duplicate they will complain it doesn't answer *their* question. In other words, they are not interested in the principles to make it work, they just want someone to make their code work for them.

Put simply, we have answers that explain fishing and some users who believe that we are all here to give them a fish.

The key with determining if someone wants this is that the user tries to **explain why existing answers won't work**. I call shenanigans on any user who pulls the quote in the question. If you know about the other answers **why didn't they work in your case?** The funny thing is that questions like that tend to be really good because they cover some obscure edge case, but they're growing in a forest of "Make it work for my case now!" questions.

I once asked [this MSE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307637/end-the-edit-grace-period-upon-two-or-more-spam-rude-flags-being-raised) and you'll note I put my own advice to work in both linking and quoting a similar question, even though it was asking for nearly the same thing. As such, nobody suggested it was a duplicate.

Answer (score 10):

> Is "I'm looking for another solution" enough of a reason for a question to not be a duplicate?

In some cases, yes.

There are some answers here that prescribe placing a bounty on the original question. However, we must realize that low-rep users are more likely to find themselves in this situation than any other category of users. Also, a user with less than 50 rep cannot place a bounty.

I think OP's best bet is to make their question different. **One very efficient way to do this is for OP to state what they have tried while subtly referencing the old question and why those approach(es) did not work for them**. This way, OP would have raised an entirely different question and it would be inaccurate to mark as duplicate.

To further buttress my point, consider the table below:

[image]

Although, questions 2, 3, and 4 all reference the exact same topic as question 1, none of them can be flagged as its duplicate.

Comment: Questions 2,3,4 may be motivated by the desire for another solution, but they have a specific title, not just "How to bake bread differently?", which would be the equivalent question to  "I'm looking for another solution". So it's not exactly the same situation, but it definitely points in the right direction. As for the bounty, if the rep is not sufficient, the general guidance would be to earn more rep by asking or answering good questions.

Comment: Yeah @Trilarion, you're right. But then, I believe there should be a reason why the answers in the original question are not satisfactory to OP. These reasons can be used as turning points to create a new question. That was what my illustration was based on.

Comment: You are exactly right and this is the important point here. Without knowing this reason, we cannot do anything and must leave the question closed. Only if the OP reveals it, the question has a chance.

Comment: You forgot "How to bake bread without bread".

Answer (score 4):

To determine if something is a dupe or not requires technical expertise. So what matters is what the domain experts think should be done with the post. The OP might be a domain expert with more knowledge than those who closed the post, or they might have less knowledge and not realize that their question is a FAQ.

In either case the OP needs to specify in technical terms exactly why their question is not a duplicate, in order to merit re-opening. Or explain why the answers to the proposed duplicate won't work. Subjective opinions such as "I want better" by the OP or others are irrelevant - specify what better means.

Generally I'd step away from close or re-open voting/reviewing such posts unless I have a gold badge in the topic. As soon as several "gold badgers" get involved in moderating the post, it will most often come down to some sensible consensus.

Answer (score 3):

I think that this is one of those cases that bounties work great on.

I would encourage that they use them, as long as they have the rep.

Bounties incentivize new eyes to look at a question, and to provide better answers. They especially work well when answers hold out-of-date information.

Edit: to clarify, I am talking about adding a bounty to the question that didn't have good enough answers, **not** the question that was closed. That question should have been closed.

Comment: The duplicate question should remain closed then?

Comment: Yeah, that's part of what I'm saying.

Answer (score 1):

If the answers in the original question are not suitable for OP needs, then OP should add more details on why these answers do not work for him, by editing the question, referring to the duplicate and explaining why his question is different from the original. Once the question is edited in a way that the answers from the original question no longer apply, then it is no longer a duplicate.

Very basic example: "How to delete a file" is a question and an answer may be "use `rm`". If OP asks "How to delete a file" and it's flagged as duplicate, but he says he dislikes the answers because they use `rm`, then question should actually be "How to delete a file without using `rm`", which is not a duplicate. Making the same question again doesn't guarantee that the answers will be different.

So OP should clarify a lot on which types of answers are not valid for his question, since this will save time to users and direct them towards an appropiate answer. So no, "I'm looking for more options" is not a valid excuse, since it may mislead users in replying with the same answers as in the original question.

If the answers from the original question can actually work with OP requirements, and he just dislikes them, the duplicate question should remain closed. OP may start a bounty on the original question to attract for more variate answers.

Answer (score -11):

Yes, if and only if the reason they are seeking other answers makes their question different or more specific, and this is clearly stated in the question.