# What should I do when a question was edited so my answer is no longer valid?

Tags: discussion, edits, answers

In *[What enables a function trait type to be used where an fn type is expected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70507880/what-enables-a-function-trait-type-to-be-used-where-an-fn-type-is-expected/)*, in the [first revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/70507880/1), the question contradicted the code (the question was, though it was not clear to me, the same as the current revision, and the code was the opposite: creating `fn` and treating it as `Fn`).

I answered the question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/70515509/7884305) (and, embarrassingly, downvoted the other answer, because I thought it to be wrong), but then the OP clarified his meaning and edited the code. Now my answer is no longer valid.

What should I do now?

- Leave the answer for future readers, in case they'll have the original question (though I'm in doubt whether they'll find it when the question is different).
- Delete the answer.
- Delete the answer, but create a new question and answer it myself so SO does not lose this answer.

This is not the same as *["What to do when someone answers" - Don't be a chameleon, don't be a vandal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332820/what-to-do-when-someone-answers-dont-be-a-chameleon-dont-be-a-vandal)*, because here the question was not changed completely, but rather the code was changed to to match the text.

Comment: FYI, if you find a (good) reason to edit the answer,  you can then retract your DV

Comment: Regarding the last point - does that basic answer exist elsewhere in other questions? Creating another duplicate just to preserve an answer you wrote does not benefit the community.

Comment: @charlietfl Not that I've found.

Comment: @gnat Nope - edited to explain.

Comment: @chrisneilsen I've read in multiple places that making a trivial edit to unlock a vote is acceptable. I don't think it should be standard behavior, but it's also not necessary to wait for a substantial edit if you just wish to retract a vote you cast by mistake. Personally, I believe the benefit of voting appropriately, including rectify a mistaken vote, outweighs the overhead of making a trivial edit. This assumes you have the 2k+ privilege to apply edits immediately.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman how about I edit the question to ask *both* how conversion from fn to Fn works *and* how conversion from Fn to fn works? Imo this would be most helpful to future readers. And both answers would be correct.

Comment: @MaxHeiber That's interesting, but we end up with a question that wasn't the intention of the OP.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Max is the OP

Comment: I would flag the behavior of the question author and possibly downvote the question, or if it wasn’t that much trouble, edit my own answer. However, users who invalidate questions like that, typically will do it more than once.

Comment: @SecurityHound why flag the behavior? It was an honest mistake. The question as originally written had text and a misleading example that didn't match the text. I updated the question so the example matched the text. If we're being really pedantic here, then the question marked as correct is indeed correct and ChayimFriedman's answer was "wrong". But imo both answers are valuable and worth preserving for people who might land on the question from Google.

Comment: Another solution is for me to ask a second, separate question that corresponds to ChayimFriedman's example, and @ChayimFriedman can move his answer there. We can link to this question and answer from the current question so it's discoverable. Would that satisfy all the constraints?

Comment: @MaxHeiber Isn't this my third solution?

Comment: @blackgreen Oops. Didn't noticed that.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman, good point, I took your third option, can you post there please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70549985/what-enables-a-closure-type-to-be-used-where-a-function-pointer-type-to-be-used. Apologies for inconvenience.